# What does "find $\frac{dV}{dt}$ in terms of $\frac{dx}{dt}$" mean?

Tags: calculus

I would understand if it said  "find $\frac{dV}{dt}$ " because that would mean, 'what happens to volume as the time changes", but what does it mean to be  in terms of $\frac{dx}{dt}$"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{dV}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}$$ And most likely, you have some formula for $V$ in terms of $x$ from which you can be more explicit with $\frac{dV}{dx}$.

Answer (score 1):

Write down volume as a function of $x$. Then take a time derivative of both sides. Example for a sphere:

$V=\frac{4}{3}\pi x^3\Rightarrow dV=4\pi x^2 dx$ Then divide both sides by $dt$.